# Flash and image compressor

Tags: compression, website, flash

In my Flash site is loading slow. I want to speed up my site. How can I speed up the site? Tell me about Flash and image compression.

Comment: It should be noted that Flash is pretty much obsolete now (it was on its way out even in 2010). You should really consider moving your site to more modern technologies.

Answer (score 2):

For images with many, varying colors (for example, photos), JPEG is the best format. Your image editor should allow you to choose the JPEG compression (usually on a scale of 1-100). Try saving it at 75 or lower. Try reducing the number until you see the artifacts appear and then resave slightly higher.

For images with few colors or large blocks of identical color (for example, diagrams, cartoons), PNG is the best format. Try PNG8 (256 colors) as opposed to PNG24/32 (16.7 million colors). If you only have a few colors try reducing the color palette size if your image editor allows it.

You can usually reduce PNG files a bit further with `pngcrush` although the savings it can provide are not as great as choosing an the appropriate PNG color format in the first place.

You might also want to consider your hosting plan with your ISP. A budget plan might not offer the same performance as a higher plan.

Flash I can't help with, sorry. I'm not a fan.